# Java JUnit testing program output with given test cases

Tags: java, testing, junit

For my college exercises I have some test cases for every exercise! 
So for each of the given inputs what the program should output(print), Everything is being printed from the Main() method, so there's no method that returns the output!

Example:

```
Input:
5 10
Output:
Result of 5+10 equals 15
```

Is there a way with JUnit Testing to add all the String test cases and when I run the Java Command Line program to check if for all those inputs the output of my program is the same with the expected outputs?

Example of our college testing site:
[image]

Comment: Think of it this way: JUnit replaces your `main` method. Instead of calling your code from `main`, it should be called from the test.